# link list in c, explanation of code lines?

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list

I am just started learning linked list in c. I still confuse the line 1 in the code.
1. what is temp->data, is it pointer ? variable?
2. what is  temp->next=head, here head has NULL value???? if so, temp->next become NULL now ???
really screwed on this lines please,help me. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test_struct{
    int data;
    struct test_struct *next;
};

struct test_struct* head=NULL;

int main()
{

    head = NULL;
    struct test_struct* temp = (struct test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct test_struct));
    if(NULL==temp)
    {
        printf("error in memory");
        return 0;
    }
    temp->data=5;    // line  1      <----------  what's going on
    temp->next=head; // line 2       <----------  what's going on here?
    head=temp;
    printf("%p\n",head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> what is temp->data, is it pointer? variable?

Well, let's break it down:

1. what is temp? It's declared as

   ```
   struct test_struct* temp = ...
   ```

   so we know it is a pointer to `struct test_struct`.
2. what is `temp->data`? It means *follow (dereference) the pointer, and get the member called data*. Your test_struct is declared as

   ```
   struct test_struct {
     int data;
     struct test_struct *next;
   };
   ```

   so, we know it has an integer member called data. `temp->data` is a reference to that integer.

---

> what is temp->next=head, here head has NULL value???? if so, temp->next become NULL now ???

This code *assigns* NULL to the pointer `temp->next`.

If you're confused about this stuff, learning to step through it in a debugger might help (as would a good book).

Answer (score 1):

The `->` operator follows a pointer to a structure to reference one of the structure's elements. In this case:

```
temp->data = 5;
temp->next = head;
```

`temp` is a pointer to a struct of type `struct test_struct`, and that struct has members named `data` and `next`. These two statements assign values to those two members, in the struct pointed to by `temp`.

Since `head` was set to be `NULL` earlier in the code, it is indeed the case that the second statement sets the `next` member to be `NULL`.

Technically speaking, each of `temp->data` and `temp->next` is an ***lvalue*** (pronounced "ell value"), which means that they can be used both for the value they reference as well as for the location of where the value is stored. The "l" stands for "left" as a mnemonic that suggests that these things are what you have on the left-hand side of an assignment statement.

Comment: in the temp-> next= head, next pointer got NULL value as head is NULL ?

Comment: Yes. The right-hand side of an assignment indicates a value to store. In this case, the value comes from the `head` variable, which we can see was assigned the value `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

What is your code does is it creates a variable name "temp" which is a type of test_struct*. then it allocate memory and point the variable temp to that memory piece. This temp variable is a pointer that points to memory piece you created using malloc. inside "temp" it have two variable name data and next. in C, to access a member you use -> operator. (Line 1) you saves integer 5 to data variable in temp. in Line 2, you assign NULL to next (at this point your head is null[get it! your head is null :)]). then you points the head to the memory piece where temp was pointing. now if you printf("%d", head->data) it will print 5.

I commented each line in your code. Hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct test_struct{
    int data;
    struct test_struct *next;
};
struct test_struct* head = NULL; //Creates a global variable head. its type is test_struct* and it is currently set to NULL
int main(){
    head = NULL; //
    struct test_struct* temp = (struct test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct test_struct));// creates a variable named temp which is a test_struct* type.
    if(NULL==temp){ //at this point if temp is NULL, it imply that above line failed to allocate memory so there is no point executing this program so we return.
        printf("error in memory");
        return 0;
    }
    temp->data=5; // in the structure test_struct there is a member variable data inside it and since the temp variable is of type test_struct, temp also has data member. so we can access it by using -> operator. since data is a integer type we can assign a number to it.
    temp->next=head; //At this point head is NULL. So we are pretty much assigning NULL to temp->next
    head=temp; //When using link list we usually keep the head pointing to the beginning of the link list.(unless its a circular link list). This line does the exact same. It points the dead to memory piece that temp pointing to. 
    printf("%p\n",head);
    return 0;
}
```